# Default document in Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

Is it possible to specify the equivalent of a default document for directories in Google App Engine so that navigating to that directory automatically redirects to its index.html for example, if it contains one?

If I have this in my app.yaml:

```
- url: /demos
  static_dir: demos
```

and the demos directory contains an index.html page, how can I tell App Engine to automatically redirect to that page?

Comment: You should clarify which programming language you're using on GAE. I'm going to guess Python?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

App Engine uses regular expression matches on the request path to determine what script to call or document to serve. If you just have the one index document, you can do it like this:

```
- url: /demos/
  static_files: demos/index.html
  upload: demos/index\.html
```

More generally, you can define static files for paths ending in slashes ('directories') like this:

```
- url: /(.*)/
  static_files: \1/index.html
  upload: .*/index\.html
```

Comment: So the answer is "not really" but this is pretty close.

Comment: @dez How is this different to what you expected?

Answer (score 7):

I got this to work by using this in my yaml.

```
- url: /(.+)
  static_files: static/\1
  upload: static/(.+)

- url: /
  static_files: static/index.html
  upload: static/index.html
```

Replace static with demos and you should be set. It redirects the blank domain to index.html and al others to the static folder.

Comment: Yay! This works where many previous attempts have not. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For GAE/J, add the following to your web.xml file.

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

`www.example.com/test/` will now serve `www.example.com/test/index.html`

Comment: I believe the OP is asking how to do this in a python project.

Answer (score 1):

```
- url: /demos(/.+|)/
  static_files: demos\1/index.html
  upload: demos/(.+/|)index\.html
- url: /demos/
  static_dir: demos
```

Comment: I guess there is no difference between `(/.+|)` (the pipe is OR) and `(/.+)?`, the latter seems more clear to me. And I also used `/.*` instead of `/.+` so user can input weird stuff like `/demos//`.